# how to change margin when the image width changes?

Tags: jquery, css

i have a fixed header and when i resize the browser window the logo on the header resizes and now i want to change the margin of the logo when the image is resized how do i do that?

this is the jquery that i use to resize the image

```js
$(window).on('load resize', function() {

    var maxsize = 2560;
    var screenwidth = $(this).width();
    var factor = 0.27*screenwidth-(maxsize-screenwidth)*0.05;
    if (factor > 2560) factor = 2560;

    $('#logo').css('width', factor)
  });
});
```

```css
CSS:
#logo{
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-left:10px;
 float:left;
 cursor: pointer;
 display:block;
 min-width:220px;
 height: auto;
 width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

Comment: `$('#logo').css({ 'width' : factor, 'margin' : margin-value });`

Comment: that was not quite what i was looking for i wanted the margin to change proportionally as the image size changes.

Comment: calculate it as you want